# Usar un autonumérico recién insertado en otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql

El `idreferencia` de sql1 se introduce en la base como un autonumérico, el de sql2 no.
Recibe un input de tipo texto que pueden rellenar o dejar en blanco, si se deja en blanco la base genera un autonumerico en sql1, pero no sabemos como intsertar ese mismo valor autonumerico en sql2.

¿Cómo puedo obtener el `idreferencia` de sql1 a sql2 para que coincidan si las dos consultas se ejecutan a la vez? `idreferencia` es PK en ambas.

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO fichamaterial(idreferencia, aparato, categoria) VALUES('$idreferencia','$aparato','$categoria')";
$sql2="INSERT INTO monitores(idreferencia, tamano, tipo) VALUES('$idreferencia','$tamano','$tipo')";
mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1) or die("Error en la consulta de insercion $sql");
mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2) or die("Error en la consulta de insercion $sql");
```

Comment: Recibe un input de tipo texto que pueden rellenar o dejar en blanco, si se deja en blanco la base genera un autonumerico en sql1, pero no sabemos como intsertar ese mismo valor autonumerico en sql2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que **idreferencia** es un campo AUTO_INCREMENT puedes utilizar mysqli_insert_id para recuperar el id autogenerado.

```
<?php

$sql1="INSERT INTO fichamaterial(idreferencia, aparato, categoria) VALUES('$idreferencia','$aparato','$categoria')";
mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1) or die("Error en la consulta de insercion $sql");
$id_ultima_sentencia = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

/**
 *  Puesto que no estoy seguro si mysqli_insert_id devuelve el id cuando este es pasado directamente y 
 *  no generado, podria ser necesario hacer este condicional para aquellas sentencias en las que se establezca 
 *  el idreferencia manualmente.
 */
if(0<$id_ultima_sentencia)
{
        $idreferencia = $id_ultima_sentencia;
}

$sql2="INSERT INTO monitores(idreferencia, tamano, tipo) VALUES('$idreferencia','$tamano','$tipo')";
mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2) or die("Error en la consulta de insercion $sql");

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, nos ha funcionado a la perfección, gracias por tu tiempo. Llevabamos un tiempo buscando la solución para un proyecto.  Un abrazo.